# Passing array of pointers to object c++

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I have to create an array of pointer to class objects.
Then I have with function AddStudent I have to change/create a new student (add his data to pointer address).
In last step function ShowAllStudents has to show all students. But I shows only the last added student.
Every new object is beeing created in array index of 0. I don't know why.
There is my code:
index.html:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

void AddStudent(Student* pointer_array[], int n)
{
    int IndexNr{}, id{};
    std::string name{}, surname{};
    std::cout << "Write IndexNr:";
    std::cin >> IndexNr;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        if (IndexNr != pointer_array[i]->Student::IndexNr && pointer_array[i]->Student::name == "none")
        {
            i = id;
            pointer_array[i]->Student::IndexNr = IndexNr;
            break;
        }
        else if (IndexNr == pointer_array[i]->Student::IndexNr) {
            i = id;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Student's name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    pointer_array[id]->Student::name = name;
    std::cout << "Student's surname ";
    std::cin >> surname;
    pointer_array[id]->Student::surname = surname;
}

void ShowAllStudents(Student* pointer_array[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (pointer_array[i]->Student::name != "none")
    { 
        std::cout << "<id>: " << pointer_array[i]->Student::IndexNr << " <Name>: " << pointer_array[i]->Student::name << " <Surname>: " << pointer_array[i]->Student::surname << std::endl;
    }
    else if (pointer_array[i]->Student::name != "none" && i == (n - 1))
        std::cout << "<id>: no data" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n{10};
    Student* pointer_array[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pointer_array[i] = new Student;
    AddStudent(pointer_array, n);
    AddStudent(pointer_array, n);
    AddStudent(pointer_array, n);
    ShowAllStudents(pointer_array, n);
    return 0;
}
```

student.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

class Student {
public:
    int IndexNr;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    Student() {
        IndexNr = 0;
        name = "none";
        surname = "none";
    }
};

#endif
```

It shows only the last edited student.

[image]

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Why `pointer_array[i]->Student::IndexNr` instead of `pointer_array[i]->IndexNr`?

Comment: *Every new object is beeing created in array index of 0. I don't know why.*  May be due to `IndexNr = 0;`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't get errors.

Comment: @Kevin I tought I got an error earlier by this, but yes, it works without class::. Thank you

Comment: @GoldenRC: Stepping through with a debugger isn't about compiler errors, it's about watching what the code does, in real time, which will almost always make it blatantly obvious to you what the error is.

Comment: @Eljay I tought every time when I set IndexNr in function it should change value in object as surname does

Comment: @MooingDuck I have tried this code with some more couts which gave me information that every object is saved in pointer_array[0], not in [1],[2]... as it should. That's the problem. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @GoldenRC I guess the reason is that you got this code wrong `i = id;` it should be `id = i;` In your version `id` starts at zero and never changes.

Comment: @john omg, that's the reason. Now it works. Thank you so much. Sometimes I make a silly mistakes like that

Comment: Why are you creating an "_array of pointer to class objects_" in the first place? You use `new` but not `delete` so your program will leak memory. Why not just make a `std::vector<Student>` to keep all the students?

Comment: @GoldenRC "_I don't get errors._" What does "getting errors" have to do with my suggestion to use a debugger? You use a debugger, when the code performs differently, from your expectations. Which is, clearly, the case here.

Comment: @GoldenRC Everyone makes mistakes but being able to plainly see the code you've written (instead of just seeing the code you think you've written) is a good skill to have

Comment: @GoldenRC: Stepping through with a debugger is _very_ different than adding more `couts`.  You need to learn to step through with a debugger.